# Split a string Until a particular character occurs

Tags: c#

```
string projectname= "1.25hr projectA";
```

How can I parse the above string value to remove the time string. The input value may use the format `1hr projectA` or `1.25hr projectA` and the output would be `projectA`.

```
projectname = projectname.Substring(0, projectname.IndexOf('r')).Trim();
```

In this line the output like 1.25h.

```
char[] delimiterChars = { 'r' };
string projectname = lstbxindex.SelectedItem.ToString();
string[] words = projectname.Split(delimiterChars);

projectname = projectname.Substring(0, projectname.IndexOf('r')).Trim();
```

Comment: Use `projectname=projectname.Split().Last();`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need to remove the string 1.25hr from " 1.25hr  ProjectA".

Answer (score 3):

Your question is *vague* one. If you want to *remove* `"1.25hr "` and the like occurrencies:

```
   string source = "my 1.45hr and 5.31hr test project";

   // "my and test project"
   string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"[0-9.]+hr\s+", "");
```

If you want to *trim* up and including the *last* "hr"

```
   // "test project"
   string result = Regex.Match(source, 
     @"[0-9.]+hr\s+(.+?)$", 
     RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Thank you. But It will return empty value for my example.

Comment: I've put `source = "1.25hr projectA"; // your example` and I've got `projectA` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple regex expression to parse the text: `Regex.Replace(rawValue, @"^[\d|.|hr]+", "").Trim()`

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("1.25hr projectA")]
[InlineData("1hr projectA")]
[InlineData("projectA")]
public void Can_parse_project_name(string rawValue)
{
    var projectName= Regex.Replace(rawValue, @"^[\d|.|hr]+", "").Trim();

    projectName.Should().Be("projectA");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. it will give the result like hr projectA. I need to remove hr also.

Comment: projectname = Regex.Replace(projectname, @"^[hr\d|.|hr|]+", "").Trim();I got the expected output ThankYou.

Comment: @Logeswari Jegatheesan you are welcome. Please select one of the answers as your chosen answer.